SQL: Formula to calculate one row minus another in the same column
To start, I have a database with several hundred thousand lines of data.
I'm using this formula to extract counts of various things into one table:
INSERT INTO Key_Figures
SELECT 'All_CompanyA_Sales', COUNT(id_num) FROM sales_database
WHERE company = 'CompanyA';

INSERT INTO Key_Figures
SELECT 'All_CompanyA_London_Sales', COUNT(id_num) FROM sales_database
WHERE company = 'CompanyA' AND location = 'London';

INSERT INTO Key_Figures
SELECT 'All_CompanyA_London_Sales_last_year', COUNT(id_num) FROM last_year_sales_database
WHERE company = 'CompanyA' AND location = 'London';

etc
This might not be the cleanest/best way of doing it - but I'm relatively new to this so still learning!
What I now need underneath those however is a row called 'CompanyA_London_Sales_year_diff' which calculates the difference between 'All_CompanyA_London_Sales' and 'All_CompanyA_London_Sales_last_year'.
How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!
